# Is there a term for websites that answer a question contained in the domain name?

Tags: terminology

There exist sites such as https://shouldiblamecaching.com/, https://isitdns.com/, and https://isitchristmas.com/ that use the domain name to ask a question and show a simple yes or no answer.

Is there a term that can be used to refer to this category of websites?

Comment: *Self-explanatory*? *Single-purpose*? Is this restricted to practical sites? I'm not sure the same term would apply to the one about DNS and to [IsThatcherDeadYet.co.uk](http://IsThatcherDeadYet.co.uk). (There's also Twitter accounts like [the one about Kissinger](https://twitter.com/DidKissingerD1e)).

Comment: @StuartF Doesn't have to be practical - shouldiblamecaching.com is a joke site. That said, if there are similar but more (or less) restrictive terms I would be interested in those too.

Comment: They're just catchy, memorable site names. Why does there have to be a word for everything?

Comment: @Barmar Obviously there does not *have to be* - but if there is one, it would be helpful since I'm currently looking for more examples of them and having a way to refer to them would make the searches much easier. Isn't the whole point of asking the question that I did not know if there happens to be a convenient, short-form, way of describing it? If there isn't one, so be it, but if there was and I simply was not aware, it would have been silly to not ask. In any case, I did end up finding one close enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 3):

It's not *quite* the same thing but it looks like "[single-serving site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-serving_site)" might be about as close as it gets. It covers more than just single-question-answer style sites but they certainly do fall under this category.

Comment: http://neverssl.com probably fits your list.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a term that can be used to refer to this category of websites?

The short answer is "No".

The long answer is "As they can be discussion, satirical, serious, or humorous, it would be difficult, if not impossible, for an overarching term to apply to them all."